# Phonegap "['Media'] Plugin should use a background thread."

Tags: multithreading, cordova, plugins, background, media

I am using Phonegap 3 and the Media plugin. I keep getting these errors when testing my app on iOS:

```
THREAD WARNING: ['Media'] took '205.391846' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

I have seen this from the phonegap documentation (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html):

```
   - (void)myPluginMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    // Check command.arguments here.
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        NSString* payload = nil;
        // Some blocking logic...
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:payload];
        // The sendPluginResult method is thread-safe.
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }];
}
```

Does this go into my app as it is, or do I need to edit it for each plugin? Where do I put it?

I've seen a few posts online about this, but none with a clear answer of how to use the above code.

Answer (score 11):

Personally I haven't yet used the `Media` plugin but to handle background threads you will need to check which call is causing the `warning`.

For example if this warning throws when you are creating a `media` object:

```
var my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
```

Then you can check the plugins `.js` file (which is `Media.js`). Look for the function `Media` and look for the native call which is in this case:

```
exec(null, this.errorCallback, "Media", "create", [this.id, this.src]);
```

From this you know that this is calling the `Media` class's `create` method.
So go and open `Media.m` (or `CDVSound.m` in this exact case) and look for the `create` method (you should find it in `cordova/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media/src/ios`), end encapsulate the whole method with:

```
[self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
    // the create method goes here
}];
```

This will create a background thread for "native" Media creation.
It should look like this:

```
- (void)create:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        NSString* mediaId = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* resourcePath = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];

        CDVAudioFile* audioFile = [self audioFileForResource:resourcePath withId:mediaId doValidation:NO forRecording:NO];

        if (audioFile == nil) {
            NSString* errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to initialize Media file with path %@", resourcePath];
            NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(\"%@\",%d,%@);", @"cordova.require('org.apache.cordova.media.Media').onStatus", mediaId, MEDIA_ERROR, [self createMediaErrorWithCode:MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED message:errorMessage]];
            [self.commandDelegate evalJs:jsString];
        } else {
            CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
            [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very clear, detailed response! But question... Is it ***necessary*** do to this? Xcode provides this warning for any plugin call that takes longer than 10ms, which isn't very long (I don't think users will notice a <100ms delay). Can I safely ignore this warning, or will this warning cause Apple to reject my app?

Comment: Finally somebody provided steps on how to find the root cause.

Comment: @mattstuehler this can be necessary sometimes when the code takes longer than expected or just freezes your UI.

Answer (score -4):

1.Open your xCode project.

2.Click the setting tab 2 "Capabilities".

3.Turn “Background Modes” on.

4.Chose "Audio and Airplay".

Done.Now you can play music in background.

PS:I use xCode 6 and Cordova 3.6.3